# LockerService - Cannot set autocorrect attribute on input element

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, locker-service

When I try to set the `autocorrect` on an input I got the following warning in my browser console:

```
WARNING: SecureElement: [object HTMLInputElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} } does not allow getting/setting the autocorrect attribute, ignoring!
```

Any way I can set it? Will we support it some day in LockerService?

Answer (score 5):

Only salesforce Locker dev team can confirm this but looking into the locker API document its not supported for sure currently .Also looked into the locker code and supported HTMLElements for the input are as below

```
            "HTMLInputElement": {
            "accept":                         DEFAULT,
            "align":                          DEFAULT,
            "alt":                            DEFAULT,
            "autocapitalize":                 DEFAULT,
            "autocomplete":                   DEFAULT,
            "autofocus":                      DEFAULT,
            "checkValidity":                  FUNCTION,
            "checked":                        DEFAULT,
            "defaultChecked":                 DEFAULT,
            "defaultValue":                   DEFAULT,
            "dirName":                        DEFAULT,
            "disabled":                       DEFAULT,
            "files":                          DEFAULT,
            "form":                           DEFAULT,
            "formAction":                     DEFAULT,
            "formEnctype":                    DEFAULT,
            "formMethod":                     DEFAULT,
            "formNoValidate":                 DEFAULT,
            "formTarget":                     DEFAULT,
            "height":                         DEFAULT,
            "incremental":                    DEFAULT,
            "indeterminate":                  DEFAULT,
            "labels":                         DEFAULT,
            "list":                           DEFAULT,
            "max":                            DEFAULT,
            "maxLength":                      DEFAULT,
            "min":                            DEFAULT,
            "minLength":                      DEFAULT,
            "multiple":                       DEFAULT,
            "name":                           DEFAULT,
            "pattern":                        DEFAULT,
            "placeholder":                    DEFAULT,
            "readOnly":                       DEFAULT,
            "reportValidity":                 FUNCTION,
            "required":                       DEFAULT,
            "select":                         FUNCTION,
            "selectionDirection":             DEFAULT,
            "selectionEnd":                   DEFAULT,
            "selectionStart":                 DEFAULT,
            "setCustomValidity":              FUNCTION,
            "setRangeText":                   FUNCTION,
            "setSelectionRange":              FUNCTION,
            "size":                           DEFAULT,
            "src":                            DEFAULT,
            "step":                           DEFAULT,
            "stepDown":                       FUNCTION,
            "stepUp":                         FUNCTION,
            "type":                           DEFAULT,
            "useMap":                         DEFAULT,
            "validationMessage":              DEFAULT,
            "validity":                       DEFAULT,
            "value":                          DEFAULT,
            "valueAsDate":                    DEFAULT,
            "valueAsNumber":                  DEFAULT,
            "webkitEntries":                  DEFAULT,
            "webkitdirectory":                DEFAULT,
            "width":                          DEFAULT,
            "willValidate":                   DEFAULT
        }
```

Anything other than those are simply thrown exception by [locker code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/blob/master/aura-impl/src/main/resources/aura/locker/SecureElement.js)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mohith! I was aware of what was causing the issue, but knowing what kind of don't solve the problem I have :) .

Comment: True .Would look for someone from SFDC to put a solution. However I would still like to keep the answer so it helps someone know what's causing this

Comment: Thanks for going through the aura/ls source to find this Mohith; like Marc-Antoine I'd like the ability to disable autocorrect/spellcheck so I too hope someone from Salesforce can shed light on why this is blocked currently.

Comment: This is currently ignored by LockerService because it is a non-standard attribute. According to MDN it's Safari only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Non-standard_<input>_attributes

Comment: @TrevorBliss Can update locker document to say its not supported .The docs said its supported .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava What documentation are you referring to? I don't see any reference to 'autocorrect' in the Lightning Components Developer Guide.

Comment: @TrevorBliss Here is where I see it should be mentioned http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV

Comment: Ah yes, I'll make sure that gets updated.